# Wrap namespaces into conditional symbol (#if)

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, replace, visual-studio-2015

I'm writing a simple library for my program.
I wrote a lot classes, however after everything done I realize that I need to wrap the files with specific namespaces into `#if` conditional.

for example, I wrote an alternative implementation of `System.Numerics` under .NET 2.0:

```
namespace System.Numerics
{
    public class Vector2
    {
        //.. implementation here
    }
}
```

However, it's only apply if `USE_ALTERNATIVE` is defined, so if I target into equal or greater than .NET 3.5, I only need to remove `USE_ALTERNATIVE` from compilation symbol

The class should be like this:

```
#if USE_ALTERNATIVE
namespace System.Numerics
{
    public class Vector2
    {
        //.. implementation here
    }
}
#endif
```

however, writing #if to all classes under my custom implementations is really tedious work.

is it possible to accomplish this with find and replace that available in Visual Studio?

Comment: Could you give an example of what's going on? Like are you running your code in a different environment that can't use a certain set of classes?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon oops, my bad, yup, I mean wrap

Comment: @Compynerd255 question updated

Answer (score 1):

OK. There is actually a really easy way to do this, and it does not require you to actually use *any* `#if` conditionals at all.

Instead, simply put all of your shim classes (that's the technical term for what you're doing) in the same class library project. This will put them all in the same .NET assembly.

Then, in the referencing project, have two different build configurations, targeting different versions of .NET. In the list of references for the 2.0 config, include the library. In the 3.5 config, simply leave it out.

**EDIT:** Another solution you can use that uses `#if` conditionals is to wrap the `using` directives in your client program (instead of your shim classes themselves). That way, you only have to include one `#if` directive inside each client class that uses your library (and I would assume that your entire project only encompasses one namespace, correct?)